# Sad logic on types

Tags: java

Code base is littered with code like this:

```
BaseRecord record = // some BaseRecord
switch(record.source()) {
    case FOO:
        return process((FooRecord)record);
    case BAR:
        return process((BarRecord)record);
    case QUUX:
        return process((QuuxRecord)record);
    .
    . // ~25 more cases
    .
}
```

and then

```
private SomeClass process(BarRecord record) { }
private SomeClass process(FooRecord record) { }
private SomeClass process(QuuxRecord record) { }
```

It makes me terribly sad. Then, every time a new class is derived from `BaseRecord`, we have to chase all over our code base updating these case statements and adding new `process` methods. This kind of logic is repeated everywhere, I think too many to add a method for each and override in the classes. How can I improve this?

Comment: I guess what you are looking for are Generics.

Comment: Actually: generics plus interfaces

Comment: Actually, polymorphism, or the visitor pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution: good old polymorphism.

Simply add an abstract `process()` method to the BaseRecord class, and override it in every subclass. The code will thus become:

```
BaseRecord record = ...;
record.process();
```

If you can't add the `process()` method into the BaseRecord class (and its subclasses), then implement the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). It will leave the process method outside of the BaseRecord class, but each time you add a new subclass, you'll be forced to modify the Visitor interface, and all its implementations. The compiler will thus check for you that you haven't forgotten a case somwhere in a switch.

```
public interface RecordVisitor<T> {
    T visitFoo(FooRecord foo);
    T visitBar(BarRecord foo);
    ...
}

public abstract class BaseRecord {
    public abstract <T> T accept(RecordVisitor<T> visitor);
}

public class FooRecord extends BaseRecord {
    @Override
    public <T> T accept(RecordVisitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitFoo(this);
    }
}

public class BarRecord extends BaseRecord {
    @Override
    public <T> T accept(RecordVisitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitBar(this);
    }
}
```

Now you simply have to implement RecordVisitor for each block of logic described in the question:

```
RecordVisitor<Void> visitor = new ProcessRecordVisitor();
record.accept(visitor);
```

Comment: As I explained (poorly) in my question, there are LOTS of instances of blocks of logic like this (i.e., `switch(record.source()) { case FOO: return X((FooRecord)Foo); case BAR: return X(BarRecord)record); ... }` and `X(FooRecord record) { } X(BarRecord record) { }`) but with many different `X` methods). It doesn't seem like a good solution to just add every `X` to the base class and override. I'm looking for an even better solution. I hope that I'm making sense.

Comment: That's why my answer says: if you can't add the process() method in the BaseRecord class, then implement the visitor pattern. Each block of logic will translate into a distinct Visitor implementation. The BaseRecord class will just need one additional method, used by each visitor: `accept(RecordVisitor visitor)`

Answer (score 1):

Both Visitor Pattern and Strategy pattern can be put in use here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Answer (score 0):

I think this is instructive:

```
package classplay;

public class ClassPlay
{
  public void say(String msg) { System.out.println(msg); }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ClassPlay cp = new ClassPlay();
    cp.go();
  }

  public void go()
  {
    A someClass = new C();
    say("calling process with double dispatch");
    someClass.dueProcess(this);
    say("now calling process directly");
    process(someClass);
  }

  public void process(A a)
  {
    say("processing A");
    a.id();
  }

  public void process(B b)
  {
    say("processing B");
    b.id();
  }

  public void process(C c)
  {
    say("processing C");
    c.id();
  }

  abstract class A 
  {
    abstract public void id(); // { System.out.println("Class A"); }
    public void dueProcess(ClassPlay cp) { cp.process(this); }
  }

  class B extends A
  {
    public void id() { System.out.println("Class B"); }
    public void dueProcess(ClassPlay cp) { cp.process(this); }
  }

  class C extends A
  {
    public void id() { System.out.println("class C"); }
    public void dueProcess(ClassPlay cp) { cp.process(this); }
  }
}
```